# How to solve this second order autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE:

$$z'' +2z' + 4z - 2zz' = 0$$

where $$z=z(x)$$

I tried the usual trick when doing autonomous ODE:

$z'=p$, $p=p(z)$
$z'' = p'p$

When I plug that in, I get that

$$p'p + 2p +4z - 2zp'p=0$$

After dividing by $p \ne 0$ I get that

$$p' + \frac{4z}{p} - 2zp' + 2 =0$$

However, I have no clue how to solve this equation. WolframAlpha is not giving me any leads. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Moo I have no clue what that is. I'm a beginner when it comes to ODEs and I may have stumbled across something we haven't learned about yet.

Comment: @Moo Actually, this equation is part of a bigger problem that I got while solving a generalized homogenous ODE. It's the type where you substitute $x=kx$ and $y=k^{m}y$, $y' = k^{m-1}y'$, $y'' = k^{m-2}y''$, and where you need to find $m$, $ m \in \mathbb{R}$, so that the equation is homogenous. Though I think I've done everything correctly until now.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with what was done as this one does not appear to have a closed-form solution. You'd have to post the details so MSE'ers can look it over.

Comment: In the last term you replaced $z'$ with $pp'$ instead of only with $p$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks! But still, WolframAlpha doesn't seem to solve the equation. Maybe the equation does not have a closed form solution?

Comment: Your last equation has a solution, it is just very involved. The solution is given in "Exact analytic solutions of the Abel, Emden–Fowler and generalized Emden–Fowler nonlinear ODEs" by Dimitrios E. Panayotounakosa and Dimitrios C. Kravvaritis if you're interested. But in general, if WA doesn't give you a solution for an ODE it's most likely there is no solution/it isn't known.